# Complete a RDD based on RDDs depending on data

Tags: algorithm, scala, apache-spark, rdd

I'm using `spark 2.1` on `yarn` cluster. I have a `RDD` that contains data I would like to complete based on other `RDD`s (which correspond to different `mongo` `databases` that I get through https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop/wiki/Spark-Usage, but I don't think that is important, just mention it in case)

My problem is that the `RDD` I have to use to complete data depends on data itself because data contain the `database` to use. Here is a simplified exemple of what I have to do :

```
/*
 * The RDD which needs information from databases
 */
val RDDtoDevelop = sc.parallelize(Array(
    Map("dbName" -> "A", "id" -> "id1", "other data" -> "some data"),
    Map("dbName" -> "C", "id" -> "id6", "other data" -> "some other data"),
    Map("dbName" -> "A", "id" -> "id8", "other data" -> "some other other data")))
    .cache()

/*
 * Artificial databases for the exemple. Actually, mongo-hadoop is used. https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop/wiki/Spark-Usage 
 * This means that generate these RDDs COSTS so we don't want to generate all possible RDDs but only needed ones
 */ 
val A = sc.parallelize(Array(
    Map("id" -> "id1", "data" -> "data1"),
    Map("id" -> "id8", "data" -> "data8")
    ))

val B = sc.parallelize(Array(
    Map("id" -> "id1", "data" -> "data1bis"),
    Map("id" -> "id5", "data" -> "data5")
    ))

val C = sc.parallelize(Array(
    Map("id" -> "id2", "data" -> "data2"),
    Map("id" -> "id6", "data" -> "data6")
    ))

val generateRDDfromdbName = Map("A" -> A, "B" -> B, "C" -> C)
```

and the wanted output is :

```
Map(dbName -> A, id -> id8, other data -> some other other data, new data -> data8)
Map(dbName -> A, id -> id1, other data -> some data, new data -> data1)
Map(dbName -> C, id -> id6, other data -> some other data, new data -> data6)
```

Since nested `RDD`s are not possible, I would like to find the best way to use as possible as I can for `Spark` paralellism. I thought about 2 solutions.

First is creating a collection with the contents of the needed db, then convert it to `RDD` to benefit of `RDD` scalability (if the collection doesn't fit into `driver memory`, I could do it in several times). Finally do a `join` and `filter` the content on `id`.

Second is get the `RDD`s from all needed `databases`, key them by `dbname` and `id` and then do the `join`.

Here is the `scala` code :

## Solution 1

```
// Get all needed DB
val dbList = RDDtoDevelop.map(map => map("dbName")).distinct().collect()

// Fill a list with key value pairs as (dbName,db content)
var dbContents = List[(String,Array[Map[String,String]])]()
dbList.foreach(dbName => dbContents = (dbName,generateRDDfromdbName(dbName).collect()) :: dbContents)

// Generate a RDD from this list to benefit to advantages of RDD
val RDDdbs = sc.parallelize(dbContents)

// Key the initial RDD by dbName and join with the contents of dbs
val joinedRDD = RDDtoDevelop.keyBy(map => map("dbName")).join(RDDdbs)

// Check for matched ids between RDD data to develop and dbContents
val result = joinedRDD.map({ case (s,(maptoDeveleop,content)) => maptoDeveleop + ("new data" -> content.find(mapContent => mapContent("id") == maptoDeveleop("id")).get("data"))})
```

## Solution 2

```
val dbList = RDDtoDevelop.map(map => map("dbName")).distinct().collect()

// Create the list of the database RDDs keyed by (dbName, id)
var dbRDDList = List[RDD[((String,String),Map[String,String])]]()
dbList.foreach(dbName => dbRDDList = generateRDDfromdbName(dbName).keyBy(map => (dbName,map("id"))) :: dbRDDList)

// Create a RDD containing all dbRDD
val RDDdbs = sc.union(dbRDDList)

// Join the initial RDD based on the key with the dbRDDs
val joinedRDD = RDDtoDevelop.keyBy(map => (map("dbName"), map("id"))).join(RDDdbs)

// Reformate the result
val result = joinedRDD.map({ case ((dbName,id),(maptoDevelop,dbmap)) => maptoDevelop + ("new data" -> dbmap("data"))})
```

Both of them give the wanted output. To my mind, second one seems better since the match of the `db` and of the `id` use the paralellism of `Spark`, but I'm not sure of that. Could you please help me to choose the best, or even better, give me clues for a better solution than mines.

Any other comment is appreciated ( It's my first question on the site ;) ).

Thanks by advance,

Matt

Comment: What size of data are we talking about, for the two stages individually?

Comment: @stefanobaghino For now, only a few Mb because it is not yet in production but the aim is to cope with some Gb

Comment: Depending on the actual size of the dataset, the computing power and bandwidth within the cluster, you can even think about collecting the data you need and broadcast it. I happened to have broadcast GBs without it not being to much of a pain (we're talking about filtering TBs by a broadcast set on a cluster with a 10Gbps line connecting the nodes). I would also suggest to check if Spark is really what you need, especially if the whole dataset is less than 10 GB, well within the grasp of a commodity server.

Comment: Yes, we know we are in a limit use case of spark, but next step is to use the machine learning library of spark for some complex analysis. And we hope to grow up, so we would have more and more data to manage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to convert your `RDD`s to `dataframe`s and then `joins`, `distinct` and other `functions` that you would want to apply to the data would be very easy. 
`Dataframes` are distributed and with addition to `dataframe apis`, `sql queries` can be used. More information can be found in [Spark SQL, DataFrames and Datasets Guide](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html) and [Introducing DataFrames in Apache Spark for Large Scale Data Science](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/02/17/introducing-dataframes-in-spark-for-large-scale-data-science.html) 
 Moreover your need of `foreach` and `collect` functions which makes your code run slow won't be needed. 
Example to convert RDDtoDevelop to dataframe is as below

```
val RDDtoDevelop = sc.parallelize(Array(
  Map("dbName" -> "A", "id" -> "id1", "other data" -> "some data"),
  Map("dbName" -> "C", "id" -> "id6", "other data" -> "some other data"),
  Map("dbName" -> "A", "id" -> "id8", "other data" -> "some other other data")))
  .cache()
```

Converting the above `RDD` to `dataFrame`

```
val developColumns=RDDtoDevelop.take(1).flatMap(map=>map.keys)

val developDF = RDDtoDevelop.map{value=>
  val list=value.values.toList
  (list(0),list(1),list(2))
}.toDF(developColumns:_*)
```

And the `dataFrame` looks as below

```
+------+---+---------------------+
|dbName|id |other data           |
+------+---+---------------------+
|A     |id1|some data            |
|C     |id6|some other data      |
|A     |id8|some other other data|
+------+---+---------------------+
```

Coverting your `A` `rdd` to `dataframe` is as below

Source code for A:

```
val A = sc.parallelize(Array(
  Map("id" -> "id1", "data" -> "data1"),
  Map("id" -> "id8", "data" -> "data8")
))
```

`DataFrame` code for A :

```
val aColumns=A.take(1).flatMap(map=>map.keys)

val aDF = A.map{value =>
  val list=value.values.toList
  (list(0),list(1))
}.toDF(aColumns:_*).withColumn("name", lit("A"))
```

A new column `name` is added with `database name` to have the correct `join` at the end with `developDF`.
Output for `DataFrame` A:

```
+---+-----+----+
|id |data |name|
+---+-----+----+
|id1|data1|A   |
|id8|data8|A   |
+---+-----+----+
```

You can convert `B` and `C` in similar ways.

Source for B:

```
val B = sc.parallelize(Array(
  Map("id" -> "id1", "data" -> "data1bis"),
  Map("id" -> "id5", "data" -> "data5")
))
```

DataFrame for B :

```
    val bColumns=B.take(1).flatMap(map=>map.keys)

    val bDF = B.map{value =>
      val list=value.values.toList
      (list(0),list(1))
    }.toDF(bColumns:_*).withColumn("name", lit("B"))
```

Output for B :

```
+---+--------+----+
|id |data    |name|
+---+--------+----+
|id1|data1bis|B   |
|id5|data5   |B   |
+---+--------+----+
```

Source for C:

```
val C = sc.parallelize(Array(
  Map("id" -> "id2", "data" -> "data2"),
  Map("id" -> "id6", "data" -> "data6")
))
```

DataFrame code for C:

```
val cColumns=C.take(1).flatMap(map=>map.keys)

val cDF = C.map{value =>
  val list=value.values.toList
  (list(0),list(1))
}.toDF(cColumns:_*).withColumn("name", lit("C"))
```

Output for C:

```
+---+-----+----+
|id |data |name|
+---+-----+----+
|id2|data2|C   |
|id6|data6|C   |
+---+-----+----+
```

After the conversion, `A`, `B` and `C` can be merged using `union`

```
var unionDF = aDF.union(bDF).union(cDF)
```

Which would be

```
+---+--------+----+
|id |data    |name|
+---+--------+----+
|id1|data1   |A   |
|id8|data8   |A   |
|id1|data1bis|B   |
|id5|data5   |B   |
|id2|data2   |C   |
|id6|data6   |C   |
+---+--------+----+
```

Then its just joining the `developDF` and `unionDF` after `renaming` of `id` column of `unionDF` for `dropping` it later on.

```
unionDF = unionDF.withColumnRenamed("id", "id1")
unionDF = developDF.join(unionDF, developDF("id") === unionDF("id1") && developDF("dbName") === unionDF("name"), "left").drop("id1", "name")
```

Finally we have

```
+------+---+---------------------+-----+
|dbName|id |other data           |data |
+------+---+---------------------+-----+
|A     |id1|some data            |data1|
|C     |id6|some other data      |data6|
|A     |id8|some other other data|data8|
+------+---+---------------------+-----+
```

You can do the needful after that.
**Note : `lit` function would work with following import**

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, indeed dataframes look interesting. But is it adapted for NoSQL data format ? I think this can be bypassed making nullable fields. And this doesn't solve the need to first get the name of needed databases and then generate the corresponding dataframe to make a union of them, Am I wrong ? For now, I'll try to adapt my second solution with dataframes as you suggest, this could indeed improve it and make it easier, until I find a better way to do it

Comment: I have updated my answer and made it easy for you and others to follow. You can use sql queries in the dataframes. If A, B and C are data from same streaming mongo database then it would be better to have them in one dataframe but if they are from different sources then Yes you need a union.

Comment: The problem in your code is that you union the database data without provide the source, see in your output, data1bis has been joined but shouldn't. but I see the idea. thanks for your time and help.

Comment: @Matt, I have updated my answer which should meet your needs. I am happy that I could give you ideas to look for. :)